# SQL hierarchy - multiple level - transform every level to column

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data

I have the following requirement,

| ID | Attachment |
| --- | --- |
| 800 | 700 |
| 700 | 330 |
| 330 | 220 |
| 220 | 110 |
| 110 | NULL |

I want this result ( the number of level is random, in this example, i have null for ID = 110)

| ID | Level1 | Level2 | Level3 | Level4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 800 | 700 | 330 | 220 | 110 |

Someone can help me
Thank you a lot.

Comment: If you don't know the how depth the level can go, it's not possible like that in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these results using `join`:

```
select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id, t4.id, t4.attachment
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t2.id = t1.attachment left join
     t t3
     on t3.id = t2.attachment left join
     t t4
     on t4.id = t3.attachment
where not exists (select 1 from t tp where tp.attachment = t1.id)
```

Comment: `the number of level is random`  So this don't answer the question, you only go up to 4 depths.

Comment: @Blag . . . If the OP wants five columns, it doesn't matter how many levels there are.