# Python hierarchy - multiple level

Tags: python, hierarchy

I have this dataframe,

| ID | Attachment |
| --- | --- |
| 800 | 700 |
| 700 | 330 |
| 330 | 220 |
| 220 | 110 |
| 110 | NULL |

I want this result

| ID | Level1 | Level2 | Level3 | Level4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 800 | 700 | 330 | 220 | 110 |

Someone can help me Thank you a lot.

Comment: what you tried? Did you tried to solve for once on your own? Also didn't you ask [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68084274/sql-hierarchy-multiple-level-transform-every-level-to-column) before?

Comment: Yes I tried but I am new to python

Comment: Include that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe variable, something like this should work.

```py
ids = set(df[df["Attachment"].isna()]["ID"])
levels = {0: ids} # Gets the last level
df = df[~df["Attachment"].isna()]
i=0
while len(df)>0: # Gets the previous levels
    i -= 1
    mask = df["Attachment"].isin(levels[i+1])
    ids = set(df[mask]["ID"])
    levels[i] = ids 
    df = df[~mask]

levels_df = pd.DataFrame({f"Level{-i-j}": list(levels[-j]) for j in range(1-i)})
levels_df.rename(columns={"Level0": "ID"}, inplace=True)
```